# Offline web application + ipad bug

Tags: iphone, ipad, caching, html, manifest

I am trying to get a simple (all front-end) application working offline on ipad, but safari keep telling my that I am not connected to the internet.

- I uploaded my cache manifest,
- added AddType text/cache-manifest .manifest in my .htaccess
- I use 1 ajax request, BUT, I store it in localstorage and I check navigator.onLine, should it be offline it use the localstorage item, on ajax error it also use the localstorage item

I don't know what to investigate next.
Also it work on safari **desktop**, I can view the app offline.

the prototype url : http://www.position-absolute.com/creation/ipadproto/demos/main/index.html

Comment: Any updates on how you fixed this? I'm having the same problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out what this was.  It was indeed a Safari bug.  My application was working well in Safari but having issues on the iPad.

I just upgraded my iPad to 3.2.2 and everything is working well!